# Comitt within the transacacional even with problems

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a method that does some validation, saved in some moments using saveAndFlush but I have a problem.
It happens that if in the middle of the method there in the passage "OsbResponseDTO response" happens some shit, it does not commit anything (the "updateTicket" is a method that should give a saveAndFlush ie commit) and the connection pool with the bank is open.
What can I do to make the commit independent if there is a problem in that thread or / and the connection pool is closed ?!

Improving the question, how do I prioritize my saveAndFlush before the method that has the @Transactional annotation finishes ... that is, I want the "saveAndFlush" to be done independently if the method marked "Transactional" ended without errors

I am sorry my english skills are bad!

Comment: Run the repository calls in it's own transaction. Remove the Transactional annotation from efetivaVenda method and make sure the repository is transactional

Comment: saveAndFlush is not a commit by the way. It is only a save and flush, as in the changes are pushed to the database but they are not yet committed. If you want a commit to happen mid-way, you really do need isolated transactions as Simon hints at. So probably step one is to cut up the above piece of code into separate methods each with their own transactional boundaries.